# Match 2 lists of varying (semi accurate) timestamps

Tags: algorithm

We are trying to find matches in 2 lists of semi accurate timestamps. The timestamps are recorded on 2 different devices **with different dates** and are not 100% accurate. So bad in fact, that the Data can have invalid data points in either set. (Invalid points have no match in the other set.)
[image: example and result]

Our algorithm shifts each set and finds the lowest average "Diff". We also require that it matches most of the lists by weighting how many points matched. (The lowest diff match was often a shift value that ended with only 1 match and it threw away all other points)

Our algorithm only shifted the first point from each list, it set those points as the "origin" and blindly computed the total diff by matching 1-to-1 the remainders in each list. As soon as we got to an invalid point the average was thrown off.

[image: our shift method]

Once we found this shift that gave the lowest average diff, we later threw out points that had high offsets.

We found that our shift method does not always produce the correct initial shift, because the average diff could be so thrown off by the invalid points, it might as well be garbage.

**What's the best way to solve this problem?**

Example Raw data:

**list A: 4,35,107,150,173,227,243,305,327,362,454,514,538**   (length 13)

**list B: 501,546,567,618,678,703,725,802,822,886,907,929**     (length 12)

Matches/Solution, in format (A_index,B_index):

(2,0),(3,1),(4,2),(5,3),(7,4),(8,5),(9,6),(10,8),(11,9),(12,10)

Comment: could you add what have you already tried?

Comment: Interesting problem! Could you please provide an example of data that corresponds to the picture? The example data that you gave with A: 100,200,etc is a bit too clean.

Comment: Updated with raw data and solution, for example

Comment: You must have some tolerance as an input to the algorithm; otherwise you can match all of the shortest list to the longest list and call it done.

Comment: Suppose that the lists have lengths `n` and `m`, and it is possible for an element in the first list to match up to `k` elements in the second at a specific time offset. I have an algorithm that is `O(n * m * k^3 * log(n))`.  It is kind of complicated.  Is that good enough?

Comment: More ideas we've had: (1) make each point from list A a wider bucket/range, and score each alignment by counting how many pairs it makes into those wider buckets. (2) each point from both lists "votes" on who it matches with best from the other list. This creates a pattern with smaller cases you can solve for. (X votes for Y, Y votes for Z, Z votes for Y),,,so that match must be Y-Z and X is invalid)

Comment: We apparently have done both the methods i listed above. Method #1 is used for finding the offset/alignment. afterwards we add a new method to refine the alignment, by finding the diff and shifting within the 1 second bucket to get the lowest diff(throwing out any diffs above a threshold). then we goto method #2 where each votes on its matching data point, which throws away invalids.
This seems to work on our problem data sets.